# JPA how to define @Table with ORGANIZE BY ROW

Tags: jpa, db2, ibm-cloud, openjpa, dashdb

Is there a way to change specify a "ORGANIZE BY ROW" argument when defining a table with JPA? The code I'm working on is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANSWERS")
public class AnswerEntity {    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CLASS")
    private String answerClass;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "TEXT", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String answerText;
}
```

I'd like to add an "ORGANIZE BY ROW" equivalent to

```
CREATE TABLE ANSWERS ( CLASS VARCHAR(256), TEXT CLOB(1000000) NOT NULL ) ORGANIZE BY ROW;
```

Comment: Even if it's possible (I don't know if it is), you probably shouldn't mix physical implementation details of a database table with the abstraction that JPA provides.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could subclass the org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary and override:

> getCreateTableSQL
>
> **public String[] getCreateTableSQL(Table table)**
>      Return a series of SQL statements to create the given table, 
>      complete with columns. Indexes and constraints will be created separately.

```
public class CutomDB2Dictionary extends DB2Dictionary{

    @Override
    public String getCreateTableSQL(Table table){
        String sql = super.getCreateTableSQL(table);

        if(table.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ANSWERS")){
            sql += " ORGANIZE BY ROW";
        }

        return sql;
    }
}
```

Specify your custom DB2 dictionary in the config:

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="com.test.CutomDB2Dictionary "/>
```

Comment: Have you tried using this in bluemix with javaee7.0. I am not able to get this working for my JPA with DashDB. DashDB uses organize by column as default and JPA does not work well with it. So i am tryign to set create queries with organize by row. I was very hopeful that your solution works for dashdb but could not get it working. Could you please help.

Comment: I suggest raising this as a query with Bluemix support. This should work "out of the box", so there could be an underlying product issue that needs to be ironed out.

Comment: In which maven package is DB2Dictionary class ?

Comment: http://www.findjar.com/index.x;jsessionid=DE9148FDD4543D85D59ECCA07A48F9BC?query=.DB2Dictionary

Comment: No. It is for OpenJpa.